# Having wrong CRS from graphical modeler output

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I'm using graphical modeler to reclasify some rasters and then make another calculus, but when I try my model only with the first step (reclassify) I get an output with different crs of the input.

I'm using the r.recode function.

[image: Model]

This is the crs of the input
[image: crs from input]

This is the crs of the output
[image: crs from output]

Can someone help me to fix that?

I tried using all the option in r.recode but never get the right crs.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you run  r.recode from the processing toolbox?

Comment: Yes, I have the same result. But I found that it happens only with GRASS commands, with the SAGA or QGIS command works fine.